# implications of a successful read from Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, digest, consistency, mismatch

This is the context:

- reading by primary key (only one row should be returned)
- reading from a quorum among 3 replicas
- don't care whether quorum agrees on contents of the row
- just care whether every node in quorum has the row

This is my understanding of Cassandra read behavior.

- Cassandra reads the contents of a row from one node in the quorum
- other nodes in the quorum receive a *digest read*
- the digests of nodes are compared
- in the case of *mismatch*, the latest version of the row from any of the nodes in the quorum is returned

My problem is that I don't know what *mismatch* implies. Is an empty (missing row) digest considered a mismatch? Does a successful read imply that the nodes in the quorum all have the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mismatch implies difference in timestamp of a column for the row. A missing row is considered a failure and the Quorum consistency will not be met and no data returned. It will eventually lead to read repair on the node which did not have data.

Comment: Would you mind providing any corroborating information if you can? Even an anecdote would be ok.